# Issue converting .live functions to .on

Tags: jquery, event-delegation

Updating some code base and having an issue I can't seem to conquer. Ive read the .on documentation and feel I have a decent enough understanding of it. The form is brought in via ajax.load when you sign in. No issue there. In a simple set up such as:

```
<div id="FXCMForm">
    <form action="processor.php" method="post" id="Form1">
        <ul>
            //other li's
            <input type="submit" id="Button1" value="Create License Key" />
            //other li's            
        </ul>
        <div id="Msg1" class="error"><a class="close">X</a><ul></ul></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Old code using .live would be such as this

```
$("#Button1").live('click',function(){
$("#Form1").validate({
    errorContainer: "#Msg1",
    errorLabelContainer: "#Msg1 ul",
    errorElement: "li",
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $('#prcs1').show();
        var dataString = $(form).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            //ajax success stuff
        } else {
             //ajax fail stuff
        }
    });return false;
    },
    rules: {//rules},
    messages: {//messages}
    });
});
```

Trying to use the new(ish) .on call like so

```
$("#FXCMForm").on("click", "#Button1", function(event){
    $("#Form1").validate({
 //all other stuff here   
 });
```

Ive called the container which contains the dynamic elements #FXCMForm, the type of event "click" and the element triggering it "#Button1" but when I click, it just dumps the returned PHP data in a blank page, not doing any ajax stuff. Any ideas?
Thank You

Comment: Your code should work, as long as the `#FXCMForm` element doesn't get replaced/removed.

Comment: Edit: after this line `$("#FXCMForm").on("click", "#Button1", function(event){` add: `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently using "body" as the root element does the trick. hmmm

Comment: That means your `#FXCMForm` element is dynamic (gets replaced or removed, doesn't exist when event is bound)

Comment: Ah - if the container #FXCMForm is brought in with the ajax too, that is dynamic and thus binding events to it is lost. You need something that isn't dynamic so you can bind the events to it.

Comment: I just went up one level in the DOM and found the main containing div and it works. Greatly appreciate your help KevinB and David